# Button onClick event triggered too many times in a jQuery Mobile Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, dialog

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 and am using [Dialogs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html). I'm using the dialog to choose which element to add to a `<ul>`. I've googled and search for similar issue on SO but no luck so far.

To add multiple elements to the `<ul>`I need to open my dialog multiple times and I'm trying to avoid having to re-create the dialog each time I open it. My problem is that my `onClick` event of my `OkButtonPopup` button triggers too many times (the first time, it triggers once, the second time, it triggers twice, the third time it triggers 3 times and so on...).

I don't get why this is happening...

Below is the (simplified) code that gives me trouble.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Problem with Dialog re-use</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Problem with Dialog re-use</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p><h2>Activated by</h2></p>
            <ul id="activate_ul">
                <!-- li to be added dynamically-->
            </ul>
            <a href="javascript:addPopup()" data-rel="popup" data-role="button">Add</a>    
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div id="myDialog" data-role="dialog">    
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
            <h1>My Elements</h1>
        </div>    
        <div id="myDialogContent" data-role="content" data-theme="c">
            <p>Element Type</p>
            <select id="element-type">
                <!-- options to be added dynamically-->
            </select>
            <p>Element Name</p>
            <select id="element-list">
                <!-- options to be added dynamically-->
            </select>
            <a href="#" id="OkButtonPopup" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b">Ok</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var all_inputs = ["myInput1","myInput2","myInput3","myInput4"];
        var all_outputs = ["myOutput1","myOutput2","myOutput3","myOutput4"];
        var all_zones = ["myZone1","myZone2","myZone3","myZone4"];

        function updateInputList() {
            $('#element-list').empty();        
            for (var i = 0; i < all_inputs.length; i++ ) {
                $('#element-list').append('<option value="'+all_inputs[i]+'">'+all_inputs[i]+'</option>');
            }
        }

        function updateOutputList() {
            $('#element-list').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < all_outputs.length; i++ ) {
                $('#element-list').append('<option value="'+all_outputs[i]+'">'+all_outputs[i]+'</option>');
            }
        }

        function updateZoneList() {
            $('#element-list').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < all_zones.length; i++ ) {
                $('#element-list').append('<option value="'+all_zones[i]+'">'+all_zones[i]+'</option>');
            }
        }

        function removeByValue(arr, val) {
            for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                if(arr[i] == val) {
                    arr.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        function addPopup() {
            $('#element-type').empty();
            $('#element-type').append('<option value="Input">Input</option>')
                            .append('<option value="Output">Ouput</option>')
                            .append('<option value="Zone">Zone</option>');    

            updateInputList();

            $('#element-type').change();        

            $('#element-type').on("change", function() {
                if ($("option:selected", this).attr('value') == "Input") {
                    updateInputList();
                }
                if ($("option:selected", this).attr('value') == "Output") {
                    updateOutputList();
                }
                if ($("option:selected", this).attr('value') == "Zone") {
                    updateZoneList();
                }

                $('#element-list').selectmenu('refresh');
            });

            // Event triggered too many times!! Why???
            $('#OkButtonPopup').on("click", function() {
                $('#activate_ul').append('<li>' + $('#element-list').val() +'</li>');

                // remove element from corresponding array
                if ($('#element-type').val() == 'Input' ) {
                    removeByValue(all_inputs, $('#element-list').val());
                }
                if ($('#element-type').val() == 'Output' ) {
                    removeByValue(all_outputs, $('#element-list').val());
                }
                if ($('#element-type').val() == 'Zone' ) {
                    removeByValue(all_zones, $('#element-list').val());
                }
            });

            $.mobile.changePage("#myDialog", { role: "dialog" });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everytime you call addPopup, you keep on attaching the click event to OkButtonPopup, hence, the event handler gets called a couple of times. You can try to attach the event through bind and unbind it prior to binding. You can do it this way:

```
$('#OkButtonPopup').unbind("click").bind("click", function() {
                $('#activate_ul').append('<li>' + $('#element-list').val() +'</li>');

                // remove element from corresponding array
                if ($('#element-type').val() == 'Input' ) {
                    removeByValue(all_inputs, $('#element-list').val());
                }
                if ($('#element-type').val() == 'Output' ) {
                    removeByValue(all_outputs, $('#element-list').val());
                }
                if ($('#element-type').val() == 'Zone' ) {
                    removeByValue(all_zones, $('#element-list').val());
                }
            });
```

Or you can also attach the click event on pageshow instead of doing it in addPopup. That way you bind it only once.