# jQuery: Have same event attached to multiple controls on same page

Tags: jquery, modalpopup

I have a form on which certain questions has special `css` class associated with them. Now on `document.ready`, I have `$('.cssclassname').on` where I get some data through `ajax` call and display that returned data in that class row.

One of the components returned is a button, clicking on which brings up `jQuery ModalPopup`  and on getting data in my `$('.cssclassname').on`, I attach my ModalPopup event so that `ModalPopup` works correct through that button click.

Now problem I am facing is , sometimes, I can have 3-4 buttons on my page, every time I click on 1 button, the code to open modalpopup runs x no of times (where x is number of buttons). I think the problem is as modalpopup has same class and I am attaching same events x number of times due to x numbers of buttons.

Is their any way to solve this problem where I only attach particular event function once per page load.

I am bit confused explaining this question but let me know anyone can help me in this or needs any more clarification.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a typo: $('cssclassname').on ? should be $('.cssclassname').on

Comment: @roasted: that's just a typo, i'll still correct it

Comment: this fixed my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673384/button-onclick-event-triggered-too-many-times-in-a-jquery-mobile-dialog/11673625#11673625

Comment: This is what i told you in my answer: "unbind event before rebind it using .off()(weird)"

Comment: @roasted: example or syntax would have been very helpful, anyway thanks. I didnt knew how to unbind and then bind..

Comment: "example or syntax would have been very helpful" we could say the same about your question ;). Anyway, have you try using instead: `$(document).on("click", ".className", function(){});` ?  Because this is the right way to do that.

Comment: why i said about the example was, as i am very new to jQuery, i understand what to do but dont know ''''how to do'''', thats a reason i gave a link in my answer, you pointed me in right direction but someelse showed me ''''how to do'''' it. Apologises if you thought i was being rude.

Comment: No, no, i didn't find you rude Jay! Welcome in javascript/jquery world :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand it, you have two options:

- unbind event before rebind it using `.off()`(weird)
- use delegation with .on():

  $(document).on("click", ".className",
     function(){});

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it so add a class to all of the buttons that have this behavior and bind them in one go.

```
 <button id='modalTrigger1' class='modelPopupTrigger'>Click</button>
 <button id='modalTrigger2' class='modelPopupTrigger'>Click</button>
 <button id='modalTrigger3' class='modelPopupTrigger'>Click</button>
```

Then in JS

```
 $(function(){
      $(document).on("click", "button.modelPopupTrigger", function(){..handler..});
 });
```

alternatively you can assign the function to a variable  reuse the function for binding

```
 $(function(){
      var modelHandler = function(){... handler...};

      $("#button1").on("click", modelHandler);
      $("#button2").on("click", modelHandler);
 });
```